# Creating Nginx server block: failed for wordpress

Tags: server, php, nginx

After installing LEMP I need to configure Nginx server block according to this tutorial:

https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-wordpress-with-nginx-and-lets-encrypt-ssl-on-ubuntu-22-04.html

If I create a file:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/server.conf
```

and

```
server {
server_name server www.server;
root /var/www/html/server;
location / {
index index.html index.htm index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}
```

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/www.server
```

```
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" | sudo tee /usr/share/nginx/html/www.server/index.php
```

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

I get the following error: Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.

And

```
"systemctl status nginx.service"
```

Retunrs:

```
× nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-07-25 23:43:25 UTC; 25s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 35414 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 11ms

Jul 25 23:43:25 server1 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jul 25 23:43:25 server1 nginx[35414]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:60
Jul 25 23:43:25 server1 nginx[35414]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jul 25 23:43:25 server1 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 25 23:43:25 server1 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 25 23:43:25 server1 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I went than the other way around and created the file inside: /etc/nginx/conf.d/
But it returned the same error saying there is no file on the one set up above.

It only worked once with a simpler set taken on another tutorial:
https://bytexd.com/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-using-lemp-stack-nginx/

But then, I am not sure if it will be correct for WordPress install with Let's Encrypt.

When going back to the later one:

Now with the later tutorial, I am getting a conflict:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "server" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "server" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/share/nginx/www.theapothecary.app/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Could anyone please help?
```

Comment: I have a Wordpress config i can share you shortly  using LetsEncrypt and everything.  i'll share it once i'm back at home

Comment: Ur the most kind.

Comment: The files under site-enabled shouldn't have a ".conf" suffix.

Comment: Thanks @DidiKohen. I managed to install with another config file. Now, stuck with error: timeout for both IP and domain name. When I create a mariadb user, should I use user@localhost instead of user@ip or user@hostname(my instance name)?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is having the same problem.

This tutorial did it. [lemp=wp](https://bytexd.com/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-using-lemp-stack-nginx/)

I only had to substitute mysql for mariadb, all other steps are tested :)